# Jenkins forces to increase Max connections to Kubernetes API

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

```
Jenkins version : 2.121.3
```

I am using the k8s plugin in Jenkins which helps me deploy my sequential and parallel jobs on my k8s cluster.

Here is the part of the `Jenkinsfile` where the job fails

```
           parallel([
                    build: {
                        stage('check formatting')
                        // some code

                        stage('build')
                        // some code

                        stage('build image')
                        // some code

                        stage('push image') 
                        // some code
                    },
                    test: {
                        stage('test') 
                        // some code

                        stage('build e2e test image')
                        // some code

                        }

                        stage('push e2e test image') 
                        // some code
                    },
                   failFast: true])
```

While running a job which has parallel stages, I come across the error

```
caught java.io.IOException: Connection was rejected, you should increase the Max connections to Kubernetes API
```

Then I goto Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> Cloud --> Kubernetes and increase "Max connections to Kubernetes API" by say.... 20 and re-run the job and it works. And if I try to re-run the job after that, it fails with the same error and then again I have to increase the limit. So Im kind of in an endless loop  doing the following:

1) Restart jenkins evrerytime

2) Bump up API Server requests limit.

So Im not sure why this is happening. Is there a way for me to find out how many requests are being handled by the API server ? And whats their source ? And how can I find out if there are any lingering requests from previous jobs ?

Full error log :

```
Failed in branch build
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] echo
caught java.io.IOException: Connection was rejected, you should increase the Max connections to Kubernetes API
[Pipeline] echo
org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:329)
org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:237)
hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:188)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:99)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:278)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:270)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:178)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor646.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:109)
___cps.transform___(Native Method)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:103)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:60)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
```

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

it's looks it is the official bug of plugin

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55392

You can try comment this issue, to help community to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Max connections to Kubernetes API to 64. Sometimes, setting it too low will generate errors. Also, Set the Container Cleanup Timeout to 5.

Comment: Hi @Mike, can you give a detailed how to on setting the Max connections to Kubernetes API to 64.